# cell spacing in custom view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am newbie in iOS developing field. And i am facing trouble in creating custom collectionView cell. I have even tried changing Min spacing in size inspector from 10 to 2. But nothing is working out. Can anybody help me out.

[image]

And here is the attribute set for the custom cell.
[attribute given for the custom cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVTbb.png)

Comment: need you to add more code and possible show attributes set inside IB as well

Comment: sorry for the missing information. I have problem with the cell spacing issue and i want it to be atleast 2size.

Comment: this is collection view right ? you can set the item size in the UICollectionViewFlowLayout delegate methods

Comment: Yup it is collection view...will the delegate method above solve my problem??

Comment: it will at least make the size correct. for the other part - show the attributes you set for collection in interface builder please

Comment: sir i have shown the attribute above.

Comment: try Shreyansh answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this in the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method

```
-(CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    CGFloat minSpace = 10; //Space that you want
    return  CGSizeMake((screeWidth - minSpace) / 2 , cellHeight); //Cell height is your collectionViewCell height.
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Download [this](https://github.com/keighl/KTCenterFlowLayout) project and import `KTCenterFlowlayout.h` and `.m` files into your project then write below code in view did load It Will work Fine

```
KTCenterFlowLayout *layout = [KTCenterFlowLayout new];
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.f;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.f;
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout];
```

u can adjust the spacing between the cells by using like this

```
  layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.0;
  layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my undersanding, you have taken `UICollectionView` and use it delegate and datasource methods.

With delegate and datasource methods, use below method also.

```
return CGSizeMake(((self.view.frame.size.width-10(leftpadding)-10(top)-5(right)-10(bottom))/2) ,180);
```

Also Set Min spacing and Intents in IB of your storyboard.

[image: IB Setting]

As per my developing,my view is as below : -

[image]

Hope this will help you.